# how to deal with absolute value/norm when computing volume

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Compute the 4-dimensional volume of the set $\ E\ \subset \mathbb{R}^{4}\ $ consisting of all$\ (x,y,z,t) \in \mathbb{R}^{4}\ $ such that

$$\left|x\right|+\left|x+2y\right|+\left|x+2y+3z\right|+\left|x+2y+3z+4t\right|\ \leq a\ $$
where $\ a > 0\ $ is a given number.

My question is:  can i consider the relation

$\left|x\right|+\left|x+2y\right|+\left|x+2y+3z\right|+\left|x+2y+3z+4t\right|\ \leq a\ $

to be the same as:

$\ {x}^{2}+{(x+2y)}^{2}+{(x+2y+3z)}^{2}+{(x+2y+3z+4t)}^{2} \leq a?\ $

or could it also be equivalent to:

$\ {x}+{(x+2y)}+{(x+2y+3z)}+{(x+2y+3z+4t)} \leq a?\ $

Otherwise, I am not sure how to deal with the case of absolute value or presence of norm when computing volume.

Comment: Neither of those alternatives is correct. You could figure that out by trying some examples. To think about how to attack the problem, work out a two dimensional analogue where you can draw a picture. what's the area of the figure with $|x| + |x+2y| \le  a$?

Comment: @EthanBolker, i deleted my previous my comment realizing I made a mistake.  After thinking some more, i realized isn't what you are suggesting the same as using change of variable to calculate the area of the linear transformation $T(x,y)=(x, x+2y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true.  The sum of absolute values gives you a polyhedron while the sum of squares will give you a round object.  If you work in $2D$, you find that $|x|+|y|= a$ is a square oriented on a diagonal, while $x^2+y^2= a^2$ is a circle of radius $a$.

You are expected to set up a four dimensional integral.  As all the terms are positive, the first tells you that the $x$ integral runs from $-a$ to $+a$.  Now find the range of $y$ that corresponds to a given $x$.  That will give you the range of the $y$ interval.  Keep going.

Comment: the range of y would be between $a-4x$ and $-a-4x$?

Comment: No, you have $|x+2y| \le a-|x|$ because you can always choose $z,t$ to make the last two absolute values $0$.  You will have to condition on the sign of $x$

Comment: can I somehow turn this into a question of change of variables.  I remember in vector calculus texts, there are always examples where a parallelogram/rotated square gets transformed into an unrotated square.  So can't I just use $T(x,y)=(x, x+2y)$ and compute the area by calculating the determinant for the derivative matrix of T?

Comment: Yes, that is a good approach.  I didn't think of it.  I think it will be much simpler than what I proposed.

Comment: do I still have to set up a soubkw integral where the integrand is 1 and I input the limits of integration according to the change of variable for transformation T?